# Error con Front-end / Back-end

Tags: jquery, json, php7, apache2

Disculpa por la pregunta quizás sea muy molestoso. Tengo un problema al cargar mi página Front-end con back-end en el servidor de producción y en modo local todo las paginas funcional perfecto.

Los script de jquery  y la petición de ajax no se están ejecutando correctamente en el servidor de producción PHP 7.2.

Modo local normal cangan todo los scripts y los otros algoritmos funcionan a la perfección y es PHP 7.2

errores en la consola del navegador

```
TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function
TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function
SyntaxError: expected expression, got
ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

y todo la pagina de Front-end se me carga en el Back-end.

Estos errores no me sale cuando lo ejecuto en modo local y tampoco las páginas de Front-end se me carga en el Backend. "CERO ERRO EN MODO LOCAL".

Por favor necesito de su ayuda.

He configurado el servidor apache2 y el php.ini nose o que modulo anda mal o que necesito configurar, espero su amable ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: y los error de apache que dicen?

Comment: como cargas jquery? y los scripts?

Comment: los errores que te marca son por que no esta cargando las librerías js intenta llamar a jquery desde la consola del proyecto en produccion. si usas archivos en local verifica que los tengas descargados en el server de producción o usa el CDN.
si jquery funciona entonces revisa las otras librerías.

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita más información: ¿cómo estás cargando los scripts? ¿puedes verificar la estructura del proyecto y la existencia de los ficheros en el servidor? ¿qué errores recibes en la consola de JS? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.